# Conditional left join on a different table based on a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a long join that uses cross apply and convoluted columns. I have a parameter named @NonCAT. If this parameter is equals to "NonCAT" I want my fourth and fifth left joins to join on a different table. At first, I was thinking maybe there is a way to put an if statement there. Such as:

```
if @NonCAT = 'NonCAT'
   begin
     left join (column1, column2, column3,
                from a_completely_different_table
                where reportmonth = @currentmonth
               )
      left join (column1...
                 from the_same_table_as_above
                 where reportmonth = @previousmonth
                )
else if @NonCAT <> 'NonCat'
       begin
          left join (column1....
                     from_a_different_table_as_above....
```

Am I making sense here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can do with a single query is:

```
from a left join
     b
     on . . . and @NonCat = 'NonCat' left join
     c
     on . . . and @NonCat <> 'NonCat'
```

That is, move the conditions into the `on` clauses.  You are using `left join` so this is fine.

Of course, you can write the *entire* query twice and use `if`.  Or, construct a single query using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Writing the query twice would make the script really long as I have long joins in this query. I was thinking about that. I will try what you suggested and see if I have any luck with it.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I would probably have to write the whole query twice because it would have to select two different tables and columns for SSRS so I think the best course is to use an if statement and write it twice.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach could be not to have conditional joins, but rather in what you select, using `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE...END` (which can have multiple `WHEN`'s.)

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN @NonCAT = 'NonCAT'
            THEN t1.column1
            ELSE t2.column1
             END AS column1,
       CASE WHEN @NonCAT = 'NonCAT'
            THEN t1.column2
            ELSE t2.column2
             END AS column2,
       CASE WHEN @NonCAT = 'NonCAT'
            THEN t1.column3
            ELSE t2.column3
             END AS column3
  FROM mainTable AS mt
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
               SELECT column1, column2, column3,
                 FROM a_completely_different_table
                WHERE reportmonth IN(@currentmonth, @previousmonth)
       ) AS t1 ON t1.somecol = mt.somecol
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
               SELECT column1, column2, column3,
                 FROM from_yet_a_completely_different_table
                WHERE [conditions]
       ) AS t2 ON t1.somecol = mt.somecol
```